# NonSerialized attribute on a constant

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, constants

Browsing .NET Reference source for some details on [`ClaimsIdentity`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs) class I noticed this:

```
[NonSerialized]
const string PreFix = "System.Security.ClaimsIdentity.";
[NonSerialized]
const string ActorKey = PreFix + "actor";
```

What might be a possible reason to use `NonSerializedAttribute` on a `const`?

Comment: It needs not be serialised because its value cannot change.

Comment: const values are serializable unless they have the NonSerializedAttribute attached to them. Whoever wrote that code, decided they didn't want have those values serialized.

Comment: Well, formally `const` is a field so `NonSerialized` is perfectly acceptable based on its description. But what's the practical benefit of this? What serializer would put consts into a stream by default?

Comment: Both `SoapFormatter` and `BinaryFormatter` don't format `static` fields (and `const` is internally something like `static`)

Comment: The writers of SoapFormatter and BinaryFormatter may have decided not to fields with certain attributes, such as static, but that's not the default language behavior.

Comment: Note that the OP did not specify which formatter is in use for the posted code context.

Answer (score 0):

const values are serializable unless they have the NonSerializedAttribute attached to them. Whoever wrote that code, decided they didn't want to have those values serialized.

Read the [MSDN docs on the SerializableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), specifically:

> When you apply the SerializableAttribute attribute to a type, all private and public fields are serialized by default. You can control serialization more granularly by implementing the ISerializable interface to override the serialization process.

Comment: No. Constants (and static members) are not serialized. What would you expect when you deserialize a constant?

Comment: I would expect it to be initialized from the data set and remain constant thereafter. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Const are for whole class and not tied with instance.

Comment: Seems like a comment, not an answer.