# When should I use NonSerializedAttribute in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, nonserializedattribute

I am trying to write a class in C# with [Serializable()] mark. Then I noticed that there are some situations the NonSerializedAttribute mark is needed.

- [The event delegate could not be serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508817/6667035)
- Constant member, such as [NonSerialized attribute on a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443196/nonserialized-attribute-on-a-constant)
- Something sensitive data that need to be prevented the serialization.

I am curious about when should I use `[NonSerializedAttribute()]` in other conditions besides these rules?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: When you don't want something `serialized`, you will know when you need it

Comment: "Indicates that a field of a serializable class should not be serialized". So, whenever something should not be serialized (e.g. instance specific data)